# Convert a 3D cartesian map to Healpix projection

Tags: astropy, astronomy, map-projections, healpy

I want to convert a map I have into a healpy map. I am fairly new to working with healpy so any suggestions would be appreciated. 
The current map looks like this, in the format GLONxGLATxR(Kpc):
[image: The format is GLONxGLATxR(Kpc)]

Comment: You might be more likely to get a helpful answer on an astronomy-specific mailing list or forum.  As currently posed, I don't think this question is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `healpy.ang2pix` function, so given your coordinates you can understand which is the associated pixel.

See https://healpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/healpy.pixelfunc.ang2pix.html

As an example, see this tutorial:

https://gist.github.com/zonca/680c68c3d60697eb0cb669cf1b41c324